# Yup schema union type?

Tags: yup

How can I define a field in a schema which can be of multiple types?

i.e. something that looks like:

`field: array().of(someOtherSchema *OR* { uuid: string().required() }),`

I have looked on the yup api docs but can't find anything that seems to allow union types.

Answer (score 0):

with yes you can use "mixed" staying

```
field: yup.mixed().oneOf([yup.number(), yup.string()]).required
```

This way you validate whether the field is a string or number

sorry, my english, i am Brazillian